# Trying to pass NIC to domU causes kernel panic

Tags: linux, virtualization, centos, xen, redhat

I'm using CentOS 5.5 x64 on both the dom0 and domU.  I am attempting to pass-through a 3-port NIC (*Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8110SC/8169SC Gigabit Ethernet (rev 10)*) to the domU using pciback.  However, when the first port on the NIC is brought online, it causes the domU to crash.  Any suggestions? (eth0 is the on-board NIC, which works fine).

Edit: By the way, adding 'swiotlb=force' to the domU kernel line (as recommended in the dump) causes the domU to fail with the same error, only it happens immediately upon launching the vm.

```
Bringing up interface eth0:  
Determining IP information for eth0... done.    [  OK  ]
Bringing up interface eth1:  
Determining IP information for eth1...Fatal DMA error! Please use 'swiotlb=force'
----------- [cut here ] --------- [please bite here ] ---------
Kernel BUG at arch/x86_64/kernel/../../i386/kernel/pci-dma-xen.c:394
invalid opcode: 0000 [1] SMP 
last sysfs file: /class/net/eth1/address
CPU 0 
Modules linked in: be2iscsi ib_iser rdma_cm ib_cm iw_cm ib_sa ib_mad ib_core ib_addr iscsi_tcp bnx2i cnic ipv6 xfrm_nalgo crypto_api uio cxgb3i cxgb3 8021q libiscsi_tcp libiscsi2 scsi_transport_iscsi2 scsi_transport_iscsi loop dm_mirror dm_multipath scsi_dh scsi_mod parport_pc lp parport r8169 mii pcspkr xennet dm_raid45 dm_message dm_region_hash dm_log dm_mod dm_mem_cache xenblk ext3 jbd uhci_hcd ohci_hcd ehci_hcd
Pid: 1359, comm: ip Not tainted 2.6.18-194.el5xen #1
RIP: e030:[<ffffffff802723ff>]  [<ffffffff802723ff>] dma_map_single+0x12d/0x17d
RSP: e02b:ffff880014bedcb8  EFLAGS: 00010282
RAX: 000000000000002f RBX: ffff880014a60012 RCX: ffff880017f01870
RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000001 RDI: 0000000000000000
RBP: 0000000003724012 R08: 000000000000002c R09: ffff880000def000
R10: 000000000000002d R11: ffff880015d091e0 R12: 0000000000003fff
R13: ffff880017f01870 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000003fff
FS:  00002ad23cbecaf0(0000) GS:ffffffff805d2000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
CS:  e033 DS: 0000 ES: 0000
Process ip (pid: 1359, threadinfo ffff880014bec000, task ffff8800144b77a0)
Stack:  0000000000000002  ffff880015e304c0  ffff880011f61000  0000000000000000 
 0000000000000002  ffffffff8810b474  0000001e00000000  0000000000000100 
 ffff880016f64000  ffff880016f64500 
Call Trace:
 [<ffffffff8810b474>] :r8169:rtl8169_rx_fill+0x11e/0x188
 [<ffffffff8810c6c6>] :r8169:rtl8169_init_ring+0x70/0x9f
 [<ffffffff8810c9a3>] :r8169:rtl8169_open+0x9f/0x1c6
 [<ffffffff80420ace>] dev_open+0x58/0x97
 [<ffffffff8041e9d8>] dev_change_flags+0x5a/0x11a
 [<ffffffff804534d2>] devinet_ioctl+0x235/0x59c
 [<ffffffff804162b2>] sock_ioctl+0x1c1/0x1e5
 [<ffffffff80244265>] do_ioctl+0x21/0x6b
 [<ffffffff80231924>] vfs_ioctl+0x457/0x4b9
 [<ffffffff8024ea38>] sys_ioctl+0x59/0x78
 [<ffffffff80260106>] system_call+0x86/0x8b
 [<ffffffff80260080>] system_call+0x0/0x8b


Code: 0f 0b 68 f6 7e 49 80 c2 8a 01 4d 85 ed 74 11 49 8b 85 18 02 
RIP  [<ffffffff802723ff>] dma_map_single+0x12d/0x17d
 RSP <ffff880014bedcb8>
 <0>Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a faulty NIC driver.  My research indicates that I could have patched and recompiled the driver, but it was easier to just swap in a different NIC.